# Spinner not loading in external links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an application in which I have internal and external links. i noticed that Jquery mobile does not load the spinner when an external link is clicked:

Example

```
<a href = "/products">Spinner is shown </a>

<a href = "othersite.com" rel = "external">Spinner is NOT shown </a>
```

I have tried :

```
$('a[href][rel=external]').click(function(){  //doesnt work
     $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

 }
```

and:

```
$('a[href][rel=external]').click(function(){
// shows the spinner but it gets stuck forever
     $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    $('#loadingDiv').div("refresh");


}
```

can someone help me show the spinner when the rel = external links are clicked?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle please

Comment: sure, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/RqkYM/4/  you can see the spinner shows before the error.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false")
>   have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external"
>   should be used when linking to another site or domain, while
>   data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your
>   domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions,
>   the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax
>   behavior.

You wouldn't get a loading spinner as it is just going to do a page redirect. Also for your jsfiddle, google.com will not work as they don't allow iframe access. If you change it to another site like http://jsfiddle.net it will switch the site properly.

If you MUST show the spinner, you can do something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/RqkYM/10/

```
$('a[href][rel=external]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
     $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');

});​
```

It will display the spinner then do a redirect

Comment: Think of it like this: The spinner is part of your current page/DOM. As long as you stay in the DOM by loading pages via JQM-Ajax, you can toggle the spinner. When you changepage with `rel=external` you are "dumping the DOM" including the spinner in order to load a new page. Therefore, you technically can't show the spinner on non-Ajax links

Comment: Thanks for your help. However I need that spinner to work on the external site because I get the link dinamically from my server. In case the server is down, the application seems to be stuck (even though it is not) while it is waiting for response. After 10 seconds, it times out and it displays an error message. those 10 secs, my application seems to be non responsive

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could load the external page with `$.mobile.changePage()`  See [here for docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) 
It has a `showLoadMsg` option that "Decides whether or not to show the loading message when loading external pages."

EDIT:

Here is an example of loading an external page like I described:

http://jsfiddle.net/KYvDv/2/

```
$.mobile.changePage( "/gQxCN/1/show/", {
    showLoadMsg: true
});
```

Comment: changepage would just inject it into the dom

Comment: @Bot, I'd be interested to know why.  Do you have any further info?  The reason I ask is that in the docs, the `showLoadMsg` option specifically mentions, "when loading external pages".

Comment: Like I said, it just injects the site into the dom. If you are wanting to navigate away from the site, it would be better to use a true redirect. Changepage would just grab the site and throw it into the dom.

Comment: Also, your code isn't an external page, it is an internal page.

Comment: @Bot is right, my solution doesn't work for different domains.